# Copy machine code from windows executable and run on linux

Tags: c++, windows, linux, dependencies, hex

I copy the machine code of a function on Windows.

For example:

```
void func()
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

In the above case, I would copy `func()`'s hex code segment data and `printf()`'s hex code data plus other dependencies and data and relinked it on a differnt machine running linux, would it be possible to run the code on a linux machine if properly relinked?

And if so would it there be a licensing problem? (Is it legal?)

P.S. The question regards to a distributed system question.

Comment: Probably not.  The moment you touch an OS API call (e.g. to output to the screen, unless the C compiler is using BIOS or direct hardware writes, this would not work.

Comment: this question can't be answered... what about processor architecture ? what function are meant in particular (since licensing is a case-by-case-evaluation) ? what is your goal ????

Comment: If it is windows, the most probable cpu is x86 or x86-64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty vague/unanswerable question, but this would be extremely difficult, if not impossible.  You have a number of difficulties which would need addressed. Namely, the executable format (ELF on Linux, vs PE on windows),  the calling conventions between systems/compilers, etc.

The biggest issue I can think of, is that the file handling between Linux and Windows is extremely different.  Your best bet would not be to copy printf(), but to redirect that call to the windows implementation, because after all of the library function work, the low-level write to the console is very different.

Comment: It is very difficult, but it is real. There are a Wine and a CrossOver Office which are capable of running PE for windows on Linux.

Comment: Also it is very well possible the other way round. I'm developing a 3D engine and 90% of the code are OS independent. So if you compile such a module within the engine's framework, the resulting machine code will be the same for every OS, given a specific CPU architecture. So I went ahead and wrote a cross plattform ELF loader/linker. That way I need to compile the OS independent parts only once. It also means, since the OS interfacing parts of the engine are target application independent, that applications for this game engine will run on any OS the engine supports.

Comment: thnx jonathan...and others for your help...
but suppose it were a windows machine rather than a linux one
then it would be possible to use the printf and other file functions of the windows machine...but how would i re link the hex code to execute properly on the other machine...i.e, a call to c function printf would may be now point to a differnet memory location

Answer (score 6):

There is a [`wine` program (and project)](http://www.winehq.org/) which is not an emulator. It will take exe file from windows and run it in the linux directly. Most used WinAPI will be translated to linux and to X11 graphic system.

If you want just to run exe files from windows under linux - this will be the answer. If you want know how to do this, you can read sources of Wine and/or documentation of wine and/or [articles about wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) and its design. Or ask authors of the wine in mailing list.